# Help: What is the theory underpinning unit-treatment additivity for ANOVA

Tags: self-study, anova, mathematical-statistics, variance

I have read extensively about the assumptions for ANOVA, and I am experiencing confusion with the concept of unit-treatment additivity.

I would be deeply appreciative if anyone could please explain the theory in laymans terms. Many thanks in advance if this is possible.

**Here is a short excerpt from my text book**

> The equal variance assumption has a theoretical reason for making this
>   assumption in completely randomised experiments, provided that the
>   effect of each treatment is simply to add a constant quantity to the
>   response which would otherwise have been obtained for that unit.
>
> If this is the case, then the variance of the responses in each group
>   will not be affected by the treatment, and the only other thing which
>   could cause the variance to differ between treatment groups is the
>   allocation of experimental units to the treatment groups.
>
> In a completely randomised experiment this is done by random choice,
>   so it follows that the observed variances in the different treatment
>   groups are all estimates of the same variance, the crucial assumption
>   in this argument is that the effect of a treatment on an experimental
>   unit is to add a constant quantity, positive, negative or zero, to the
>   response which would otherwise have been obtained.
>
> In other words:μ= μ+ τj
>
> This is called the assumption of unit-treatment additivity. Where the
>   treatment effects are small enough to be partially obscured by random
>   variation, which is where statistical analysis is important, the
>   assumption of unit-treatment additivity is usually valid.

Comment: What is the name of the textbook? Also here is one [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2281178?seq=7#metadata_info_tab_contents) by Kempthorne which discusses the assumption in comparison to the more generic idea of "additivity" in models.